# Receiving "TypeError: Object #<EventEmitter> has no methods 'updateMyField'" in a post-save hook

Tags: mongoose

This is the relevant part of the code that I think I'm getting the error in - it says

"if (this.ended && !this.hasRejectListeners()) throw reason;

TypeError: Object # has no methods 'updateMyField'"

```
FieldSchema
  .post('save', function () {
    var self = this;
    self.updateMyField();
  });

FieldSchema.methods = {  
  updateMyField: function() {
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    // Do things here
    return deferred.promise;
  }
};
```

I'm pretty confused why it claims that there's no method - would love any kind of help you could give!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that post hooks require you to use the doc to access the object, as also explained and answered in [Why is the "this" keyword different in a mongoose pre-save hook versus a post-save hook?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30825480/why-is-the-this-keyword-different-in-a-mongoose-pre-save-hook-versus-a-post-sa/30825528#30825528).