# Why is the "this" keyword different in a mongoose pre-save hook versus a post-save hook?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

This is the relevant snippet of my code

```
MySchema
  .pre('save', function (next) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
    return next();
  });

MySchema
  .post('save', function (next) {
    var self = this;
    console.log(self);
  });
```

For some reason, in this situation the pre-save hook gives a proper object

```
{ farm: 557ce790a893e4e0118059e3,
  _id: 557ce791a893e4e011805a35,
  privileges:
   [ { instanceId: 557ce790a893e4e0118059bb,
       access: 5,
       modelType: 'User' } ],
  public: 0,
  properties: { crop: 'No Crop', name: 'Pirani Tract 50' },
  geometry: { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [ [Object] ] } }
```

but the post save hook simply logs

```
{ domain: null,
  _events:
   { save: [ [Function: notify], [Function] ],
     isNew: [Function: notify],
     init: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 0 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`post`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html#post) middleware receives the document as a parameter instead of the `next` flow control callback parameter that `pre` middleware receive.

```
MySchema
  .post('save', function(doc) {
    console.log(doc);
  });
```